# Accessing DLL with multiple classes in java

Tags: java-native-interface, jna

I have to access a third party dll which has multiple classes in my Java application. I checked this http://blog.mwrobel.eu/how-to-call-dll-methods-from-java/

But its describing a dll with just a class and some methods. How do I access each specific class and its methods in the dll. Is this possible?

Comment: Your DLL implements multiple (C++) classes, or you want to map more than one  Java class onto the same DLL?

Comment: My DLL has multiple C# classes that I want to access using java.

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the functionality you need in C-compatible functions (`extern "C"`).

For example, if I have a C++ class as follows:

```
class Foo {
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
    void bar();
}
```

Then I would need to create some wrapper functions in the shared library that will be accessible via JNA:

```
extern "C" void* create_foo() { return new Foo(); }
extern "C" void delete_foo(void *foo) { delete (Foo *)foo; }
extern "C" void bar(void *foo) { ((Foo *)foo)->bar(); }
```

If you have to do a lot of this and compile some native code anyway, you might find using [SWIG](http://www.swig.org) to be of use.  You can customize how your native classes map into Java classes and vice versa.

Comment: Thats the major issue this is a third party dll I'll have to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adapting the interface from the examples from your link. I think that if you make similar interface with loadLibrary("otherClassName",...) you will be able to load another class from this interface.

Comment: I tried placing the class name i needed in the code below but it broke   simpleDLL INSTANCE = (simpleDLL) Native.loadLibrary(
            (Platform.isWindows() ? "simpleDLL" : "simpleDLLLinuxPort"), simpleDLL.class); Here simpleDLL is the class name or the dll name ?

Comment: In this case simpleDLL is class name. The dll name is provided by the property as follows System.setProperty("java.library.path", libPath);